# In nixos, what is the difference between installing from pkgs or python311Packages

Tags: python, nix, nixos

I had an issue when I installed `Yapf` this way:

```
environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
(python311.withPackages(ps: with ps; [
  toml
  python-lsp-server
  pyls-isort
  flake8
]))
pkgs.yapf
];
```

This gave me the error:

> $ yapf autoapp.py
> yapf: toml package is needed for using pyproject.toml as a configuration file

And I solved when I did:

```
environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
(python311.withPackages(ps: with ps; [
  toml
  python-lsp-server
  pyls-isort
  flake8
  yapf
]))
];
```

Why was the first configuration giving me an installed version of yapf that couldn't import toml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the same package - you can see this by checking the source links from the [package search page](https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=23.05&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=yapf). **Adding it to `withPackages` links the Python package with the interpreter,** making it possible to run things like `python -m yapf …` or `import yapf` within the Python REPL. If you simply list `pkgs.yapf` at the top level, the package isn't linked to the Pyython interpreter, and so only things like `man` pages and executables are available in the resulting environment.